# I now want a smoothie

Tags: riddle

You go to the local farmers market in an alternate universe.

You browse various items and find that:

- The blueberries cost 4.5₤
- The gooseberries cost 5.5₤
- The lemons cost 6₤
- The satsumas cost 6.5₤
- The strawberries cost 7₤

How much are the bananas?

> Bonus question: How much is a bottle of milk "subjectively"? I mean if we all now want smoothies, we should get that as well right. Is there milk in smoothies? I'm unsure now

Comment: what's a banana?

Comment: I'm guessing 5₤ (where the gap is) is too obvious?

Comment: i was thinking that too lol

Comment: @F1Krazy I wont confirm or deny if i would savagely reject that answer if you were to post it ;)

Comment: this is nothing to do with maths then i guess

Comment: Banana is 15000₤ since in this alternate universe the monkeys rule our world and banana is a precious resource...

Comment: Outside the box thinking?  There are no bananas, since this is a "local" farmers market and bananas wouldn't be growing in the same region as these other fruits?

Comment: Is nobody else going to point out that in physics, we measure radiation in bananas?

Comment: meme answer for me is that he is in the universe of mean farmers so the farmer decides to not tell him the price at all or give no hint. so just get the mean of the numbers which is £5.90

Comment: Does this apply to me if I'm American?

Comment: Wait: a single blueberry is 4.5₤? Man, these farmers are crooks...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After looking at the answer, I can also add that the numerical price is also loosely based on...

> The fruit's colour's wavelength per the electromagnetic spectrum, at 1 pence per nanometre :)
>
>  [image]

The choice of numbers is not all that arbitrary!

Comment: Haha im sorry, this was actually the answer all along! Didn't read the answer i accepted first very carefully... Props to you!

Comment: But the spectrum i looked at were a little bit different, e.g yellow were marked at 600nm etc

Comment: Oh sorry and thanks, I was away from Puzzling for a while but I have to say that my answer was inspired by the more upvoted one. If only you could accept both answers? :)

Answer (score 34):

I think that the prices are based on:

> The fruit colour. Using the rainbow colours ROYGBIV = Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet we get Red (strawberries) = 7, Orange (satsuma) = 6.5, Yellow (lemons) = 6, etc. The blueberries are actually more like deep purple or indigo, which explains the gap in the values, the missing £5. That would be the value of a proper blue fruit. So, assuming that the bananas are yellow, then their price is £6.

> A crazy guess on the 'milk' price. I remember this experiment in school - on a circle you have the 7 colours of the rainbow. The circle is then rotated with high speed, visually 'mixing' the colours into something that should be white (never pure white though, because the original colours are not perfect). So the 'milk' colour price should be the average (£5.5) or the sum of the 7 colours (£38.5).

Comment: Unripe bananas are 50c extra?

Comment: @RupertMorrish Actually Yellow is 6 and Green 5.50. You should get your maths right first ;)

Comment: Ah, the digits were right. Who cares about the sign? (Too late to edit my mistake)

Comment: How do units of measurement work into this alternate universe? If the price we calculate applies to a quart of milk, is a gallon 4 times that amount or still the same price?

Comment: So the more spoiled the milk is, the closer it gets to the price of a banana...

Answer (score 4):

> One could also base the prices on the Alphabetical orientation of the values, with Bananas coming before Blueberries at 4₤

Comment: Yes, I also has this thought initially but this approach doesn't explain the spacing of the values.

Comment: I did the alphabetical ordering as a false lead! Throw ppl of the scent

Comment: One might say the herrings cost 7₤ ^^..

Answer (score 3):

You go to the local farmers market in an alternate universe.

You browse various items and find that:

> The `bananas` cost 4₤
>
>  The `blueberries` cost 4.5₤
>
>  The `bottle of milk` cost 5₤
>
>  The `gooseberries` cost 5.5₤
>
>  The `lemons` cost 6₤
>
>  The `satsumas` cost 6.5₤
>  
>  The `strawberries` cost 7₤
>
>  Because it's alphabetical, The `Bottle Of Milk` explains the spacing.

Comment: I agree with this answer, as much as it would be fun to base prices on colors, this seems to be a better and more logical answer to the question.